# how to pick the ios emulator from cordova / ionic command line

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

in using the ionic emulate command line (i'm assuming it's the same as cordova phoengap) how do I pick the device - either ipad or iphone tall screen.  It always defaults to the 3.5" screen.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

With later versions of Ionic and Cordova one can use any of the following commands to list available emulations. The following commands have been tested with Ionic v3.20.0 and Cordova 8.0.0:

```
ionic cordova emulate --list # List any OS
cordova run --list           # List any OS
cordova run ios --list       # List specific OS
```

And they yield something like:

```
Available ios virtual devices:
iPhone-5s, 11.2
iPhone-6, 11.2
iPhone-6-Plus, 11.2
iPhone-6s, 11.2
iPhone-6s-Plus, 11.2
iPhone-7, 11.2
iPhone-7-Plus, 11.2
iPhone-8, 11.2
iPhone-8-Plus, 11.2
iPhone-SE, 11.2
iPhone-X, 11.2
iPad-Air, 11.2
iPad-Air-2, 11.2
iPad--5th-generation-, 11.2
iPad-Pro--9-7-inch-, 11.2
iPad-Pro, 11.2
iPad-Pro--12-9-inch---2nd-generation-, 11.2
iPad-Pro--10-5-inch-, 11.2
Apple-Watch-38mm, watchOS 4.2
Apple-Watch-42mm, watchOS 4.2
Apple-Watch-Series-2-38mm, watchOS 4.2
Apple-Watch-Series-2-42mm, watchOS 4.2
Apple-Watch-Series-3-38mm, watchOS 4.2
Apple-Watch-Series-3-42mm, watchOS 4.2
Apple-TV-1080p, tvOS 11.2
```

To start the emulator with a specific OS use:

```
ionic cordova emulate ios --target "iPhone-X"
```

See also:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/#cordova-run-command

For an older installation of Ionic and Cordova I used the syntax mentioned in RipTheJacker's answer to select the device to emulate, ie:

```
ionic emulate ios --target="iPhone-4s"
```

However, to find out what the available emulations are I run this:

```
ios-sim showdevicetypes
```

This command will return a list, something like this:

```
iPhone-4s, 8.4
iPhone-5, 8.4
iPhone-5s, 8.4
iPhone-6-Plus, 8.4
iPhone-6, 8.4
iPad-2, 8.4
iPad-Retina, 8.4
iPad-Air, 8.4
Resizable-iPhone, 8.4
Resizable-iPad, 8.4
```

Comment: Or try running `./platforms/ios/cordova/lib/list-emulator-images` from the root of your Cordova project :)

Comment: On the latest `ionic cordova emulate --list` works great.  `ios-sim showdevicetypes` did not work for me.

Comment: @ShaneLoveland Thanks for that, checked out the new commands and updated the answer.

Comment: ionic cordova emulate ios --target "iPhone-X, 11.2" not working, remove the version

Comment: Note: In some setups the command `ionic cordova emulate ios --list` will yield a list that includes punctuation, which will NOT work as is for the target.  If this is you, just convert all spaces and parentheses to dashes.  ex: `ionic cordova emulate ios -l --target="iPad--7th-generation-" --no-native-run`

Answer (score 46):

```
cordova emulate ios --target="TARGET"
```

or

```
ionic emulate ios --target="TARGET"
```

Where `TARGET` is one of: iPad, iPhone, iPad (Retina), iPhone (Retina 3.5-inch), iPhone (Retina 4-inch)

E.g: `ionic emulate ios --target="iPhone-5"`

Comment: It can only be done using the `cordova` command? Or this will work if I use the `ionic` command? E.g. `ionic emulate ios --target="TARGET"`.

Answer (score 16):

**May 2018 update**

Run

```
ionic cordova run ios --target="iPhone-X"
```

You can replace `iPhone-X` by whatever comes from the list

```
./platforms/ios/cordova/lib/list-emulator-images
```

from your project's root folder (as said in [Tod Thomson's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23268414/how-to-pick-the-ios-emulator-from-cordova-ionic-command-line#comment66133485_31350074))

For me the list is

```
iPhone-5s, 11.3
iPhone-6, 11.3
iPhone-6-Plus, 11.3
iPhone-6s, 11.3
iPhone-6s-Plus, 11.3
iPhone-7, 11.3
iPhone-7-Plus, 11.3
iPhone-8, 11.3
iPhone-8-Plus, 11.3
iPhone-SE, 11.3
iPhone-X, 11.3
iPad-Air, 11.3
iPad-Air-2, 11.3
iPad--5th-generation-, 11.3
iPad-Pro--9-7-inch-, 11.3
iPad-Pro, 11.3
iPad-Pro--12-9-inch---2nd-generation-, 11.3
iPad-Pro--10-5-inch-, 11.3
Apple-TV-1080p, tvOS 11.3
Apple-TV-4K-4K, tvOS 11.3
Apple-TV-4K-1080p, tvOS 11.3
Apple-Watch-38mm, watchOS 4.2
Apple-Watch-42mm, watchOS 4.2
Apple-Watch-Series-2-38mm, watchOS 4.2
Apple-Watch-Series-2-42mm, watchOS 4.2
Apple-Watch-Series-3-38mm, watchOS 4.2
Apple-Watch-Series-3-42mm, watchOS 4.2
```

The os version (ie 11.3) might change depending on the images you downloaded and your XCode version. So if the devices in this list don't work just run the command and get your own list.

Comment: For downvoters: could you please explain why, so I could improve my answer?

Comment: Hey man. I get no results when running this 'list-emulator-images' command, but when I run ios-sim showdevicetypes or xcrun simctl list I get loads of devices.. what gives?

Answer (score 14):

I don't know why this answers are not working for me.
But what it does is doing the next:

```
native-run --list

Virtual Devices:

  iPad (5th generation) 12.2 11904882-5E5A-4941-B291-5D38F3B51E98
  iPad (6th generation) 12.2 82079A1A-87C1-47EC-BEC2-69BA97FC440C
  iPad Air 12.2 7E90921D-D166-4CE1-956F-0193EF6E972F
  ...
```

This brings me the ids of the devices so i can do this next:

```
ionic cordova run ios --livereload --target "BA4986B3-9102-4250-91BF-7DDF7D7BC60D"
```

Comment: Maybe the difference here is `run` vs `emulate`.  Using the UID worked for me while device name did not.

Comment: 3 years and still using this method, it just works.

Answer (score 2):

I've been having the same issue since ionic2. Looks as though ionic/cordova ignores ios-sim and assigns it's own at emulation run time, refer to your installed platform eg ios (platforms/ios/cordova/lib/run.js):

To view available simulators run

> ios-sim showdevicetypes

```
/ validate target device for ios-sim
// Valid values for "--target" (case sensitive):
var validTargets = ['iPhone-4s', 'iPhone-5', 'iPhone-5s', 'iPhone-6-Plus', 'iPhone-6',
    'iPhone-6s-Plus', 'iPhone-6s', 'iPad-2', 'iPad-Retina', 'iPad-Air', 'iPad-Air-2',
    'iPad-Pro', 'Resizable-iPhone', 'Resizable-iPad'];
if (!(runOptions.device) && runOptions.target && validTargets.indexOf(runOptions.target.split(',')[0]) < 0 ) {
    return Q.reject(runOptions.target + ' is not a valid target for emulator');
}
```

As long as you run the correct simulator under the list you should be fine:

> ionic emulate ios --target="iPhone-6s-Plus, 10.2"

Comment: Found this useful tip if you're looking to add your simulator to the list, just follow instructions https://dzone.com/articles/important-note-for-targeting-ios-emulators-in-cord

Comment: Thanks for specifying the iOS version.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in latest Ionic version.
First I listed all of the available devices with `ionic cordova emulate ios --list`
Next I picked one from the list and tried `ionic cordova emulate ios --target="iPhone-6, 10.3"`
the build crashed with error....
But `ionic cordova emulate ios --target="iPhone-6"` works and pops up emulator with iOS 8.4
How to start the emulator with certian version of iOS?

Comment: Did you actually modify this file "platforms/ios/cordova/lib/run.js" ? you'll need to manually modifiy it. As mentioned earlier, cordova appears ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

Some changes are happen on latest version as per June 2020, now --target command not considering device name instead, need to place UDID of target simulator device.

Step 1:
ionic cordova run ios --list

Virtual Devices:

[native-run]   iPhone 11 Pro Max 13.6 0C6BD29C-7507-XXXX-XXXX-2CE2XXXX
[native-run]   iPhone 8 13.6 CEAE9A99-703F-XXXX-XXXX-10647A9XXXX

Step 2:

Copy only the UDID of particular device for example "0C6BD29C-7507-XXXX-XXXX-2CE2XXXX"

Step 3:

Run the following command

ionic cordova emulate ios -l --external  --target="0C6BD29C-7507-XXXX-XXXX-2CE2XXXX"

Runs successfully as on versions

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.10.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.0.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.26
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.26
@angular/cli                  : 8.3.26
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 5.1.1
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 22 other plugins)

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/kushal/Library/Android/sdk)
ios-deploy        : 1.10.0
ios-sim           : 8.0.2
NodeJS            : v12.18.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm               : 6.14.6
OS                : macOS Catalina
Xcode             : Xcode 11.6 Build version 11E708